# .NET access to 802.15.4 Wireless Transceiver

Tags: c#, c++, python

Dear Stack Overflow community,

I'm writing in hopes that you might be able to help me connect to an 802.15.4 wireless transceiver using C# or C++.  Let me explain a little bit about my project.  This semester, I spent some time developing a wireless sensor board that would transmit light, temperature, humidity, and motion detection levels every 8 seconds to a USB wireless transceiver.  Now, I didn't develop the USB transceiver.  One of the TA's for the course did, and he helped me throughout the development process for my sensor board (it was my first real PCB).

Now, I've got the sensor board programmed and I know it's sending the data to the transceiver.  The reason I know this is that this TA wrote a simple python module that would pull the latest packet of information from the transceiver (whenever it was received), unpack the hex message, and convert some of the sensor data into working units (like degrees Celsius, % relative humidity, etc.)

The problem is that the python module works on his computer (Mac) but not on mine (Windows 7).  Basically, he's using a library called zigboard to unpack the sensor message, as well as pyusb and pyserial libraries in the sketch.  The 802.15.4 wireless transceiver automatically enumerates itself on a Mac, but runs into larger issues when running on a PC.  Basically, I believe the issue lies in the lack of having a signed driver.  I'm using libusb to generate the .inf file for this particular device... and I know it's working on my machine because there is an LED on my sensor board and on the transceiver which blink when a message is sent/received.  However, when I run the same python module that this TA runs on his machine, I get an error message about missing some Windows Backend Binaries and thus, it never really gets to the stage where it returns the data.

But, the larger issue isn't with this python module.  The bigger issue is that I don't want to have to use Python.  This sensor board is going to be part of a larger project in which I'll be designing a software interface in C# or C++ to do many different things (some of which is dealing with this sensor data).  So, ultimately I want to be able to work in .NET in order to access the data from this transceiver.  However, all I have to go on is this python sketch (which wont even run on my machine). I know the easiest thing to do would be to ask this TA more questions about how to get this to work on my machine... but I've already monopolized a ton of his time this semester regarding this project and additionally he's currently out of town.  Also, his preference is python, where as I'm most comfortable in C# or C++ and would like to use that environment for this project.  Now, I would say I'm competent in electronics and programming (but certainly not an expert... my background is actually in architecture).  But, if anyone could help me develop some code so I could unpack the sensor message being sent from board, it would be greatly appreciated.  I've attached the Python sketch below which is what the TA uses to unpack his sensor messages on his machine (but like I said... I had issues on my windows machine).  Does anyone have any suggestions?

Thanks again.

```
from zigboard import ZigBoard
from struct import unpack
from time import sleep, time

zb = ZigBoard()
lasttime = time()

while True:
    pkt = zb.receive()
    if pkt is None:
        sleep(0.01)
        continue
    if len(pkt.data) < 10:
        print "short packet"
        sleep(0.01)
        continue

    data = pkt.data[:10]
    cmd, bat, light, SOt, SOrh, pir = unpack("<BBHHHH", data)
    lasttime = time()

    d1 = -39.6
    d2 = 0.01 

    c1 = -2.0468
    c2 = 0.0367
    c3 = -1.5955E-6

    t1 = 0.01 
    t2 = 0.00008

    sht15_tmp = d1 + d2 * float(SOt);
    RHL = c1 + c2 * SOrh + c3 * float(SOrh)**2
    sht15_rh = (sht15_tmp - 25.0) * (t1 + t2 * float(SOrh)) + RHL

    print "address: 0x%04x" % pkt.src_addr
    print "temperature:", sht15_tmp
    print "humidity:", sht15_rh
    print "light:", light
    print "motion:", pir
    print
```

Comment: I can't help directly, but I'd suggest possibly first get a C/C++ interface working to the raw data. Then expose this to the .net world using P/Invoke.

Comment: Any thoughts on how to get a C/C++ interface working to get to the raw data?  This is exactly what I'd like to start with... but I just don't quite know where to begin.

Comment: From what I've read I believe your problem lies in making the USB communication between your embedded board and your Windows PC work, not actually related to the IEEE 802.15.4 transceiver, right? So the first thing to do is find out how the TA implemented the USB driver and try to port it to Windows.

Comment: Hi Thomas. The sensor board is definitely sending the packets correctly, and I can tell it's coming over to the transceiver (even on my machine) because of the blinking LED's.  But, I can't seem to get access to the raw data streaming over to the USB transceiver.  As far as the driver... I used INF Wizard included in libusb [link](http://sourceforge.net/apps/trac/libusb-win32/wiki) to create the proper driver information.  Essentially, when connecting the USB transceiver the first time (before using libusb) it was unrecognized by my computer.

Comment: I then installed libusb and use the INF wizard to generate the .inf file on my computer specific for this device (it asks for product information and vendor id, etc.)  Once I created the inf file, the driver was installed and the device worked as expected (the LED lights on the transceiver blinked when the sensor board sent the packet).  Does this help explain where I am?  Unfortunately, I don't have the firmware the TA used when he programmed the transceiver.  I just have the python module that he used to unpack the data.

Comment: The library allows user space applications to access many USB device on Windows in a generic way without writing any line of kernel driver code.  http://sourceforge.net/apps/trac/libusb-win32/wiki - does this USB driver help you?

Comment: Hi Preet.  The libusb library was helpful... but I had already installed it.  Before installation, the transceiver was unrecognized, but after using the libusb INF wizard, the drivers were installed and the transceiver began working as expected (LED's were blinking when messages were received).  The problem is that I don't know how to get at the raw message data that the transceiver receives from the sensor board.  The only thing I have to go on is the python module, which wont load on my machine I think because pyusb and libusb have some sort of conflict.  Any ideas on how to do this in .NET?

Comment: Are you doing Zigbee, or just the lower layers? The company I work for used to sell a Zigbee analyzer.... Looks like most of the work done to communicate via USB to the board is in the ZigBoard object - right? If so, you would need to replicate the USB I/O functionality elsewhere. You might to look at the following link for guidance: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff540174%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

Comment: Can you post what Python says about your missing backend drivers?

Comment: What chip does it use to communicate with the computer ? (FTDI ?) You will definitely have better luck with the hardware vendor's drivers. What's the vendor ID and product ID ?

Comment: @andyopayne in file http://simonetti.media.mit.edu/dev/projects/zigboard/repository/revisions/8d4f50444f53/entry/zigboard/interface.py#L21 have communicate of especific port `/dev/cu.usbserial*`. It not always same port in different systems. You not have exception generate type `no ports found`? What first error occur?

Comment: I found the ZigBoard USB module written in Python: http://simonetti.media.mit.edu/dev/projects/zigboard/repository/revisions/7e984457f79a/entry/zigboard/usb_interface.py is that the correct one ?

Comment: This a x64 or x86 installation of Windows 7?  It sounds like you should use a virtual machine of a 32-bit installation of windows.  This allows you to use unsigned drivers or simply turn the feature off that requires you use signed drivers but I don't suggest that.

Comment: Before trying to port to another language, I`d highly recommend getting the existing library call working under python.  I have a feeling otherwise you'll take the long way around and end up back here.

Comment: To do a port you need the source to ZigBoard(). Hopefully the driver interface is in there. The python you posted doesn't  do any driver calls.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks everyone for the help.  The key to everything was using [LibUSBDotNet](http://sourceforge.net/projects/libusbdotnet/).  Once I had installed and referenced that into my project... I was able to create a console window that could handle the incoming sensor data. I did need to port some of the functions from the original Zigboard library... but on

Answer (score 0):

I'm not 100% sure on exactly how to do this but after having a quick look around I can see that the core of the problem is you need to implement something like the ZigBoard lib in C#.

The ZigBoard lib uses a python USB lib to communicate using an API with the USB device, you should be able to [LibUsbDotNet](http://sourceforge.net/projects/libusbdotnet/) to replicate this in C# and if you read though the ZigBoard libs code you should be able to work out the API.